# Trying to retain data that is getting lost with bind_rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I am trying to create an excel worksheet that combines a lot of dataframes into 1. I produced 119 logistic regression models. Then I turned the results into dataframes so that I was able to perform certain manipulations. Now I am trying to put all the results in 1 worksheet in excel rather than having 1 worksheet per dataframe. When I use bind_rows, some of the data is lost. I am not sure how to retain it. Especially as I am not sure what kind of data it is. But there is data off to the left for each observation. You can look at the attached photo for reference (says "Intercept", "age", etc). Is there a way to convert these to to a variable so that they are retained when I use bind_rows?

[image: Example dataframe]

Comment: Have you tried `rownames_to_column()` from the `tidyverse`?

Comment: This ended up working. Sorry for the late response. Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating some fake data based on the example you provided:

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <- data.frame(
  beta = rnorm(5), 
  SE = rnorm(5), 
  zvalue = rnorm(5),
  pvalue = rnorm(5), 
  padjust = rnorm(5), 
  row.names = c("(Intercept)", "ErythritolArea", "age", "BMIfactor>=40 and <50", "BMIfactor>=50")
)

foo2 <- data.frame(
  rowname = c("(Intercept)", "ErythritolArea", "age", "BMIfactor>=40 and <50", "BMIfactor>=50"), 
  beta = rnorm(5), 
  SE = rnorm(5), 
  zvalue = rnorm(5),
  pvalue = rnorm(5), 
  padjust = rnorm(5)
)
```

You can convert rownames in `foo` using `rownames_to_column()` and then use `bind_rows()` as you need it:

```
foo %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  bind_rows(foo2)
```